# Mixing in IoC containers in asp.net mvc website project with Sitecore 8.2 and latest glass mapper

Tags: glass-mapper

We are in the process of upgrading website (sitecore 7.2 + glass.mapper 4.0 + glass.mapper.castlewindsor) to sitecore 8.2 + glass.mapper 4.3. Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor has been discontinued and I came across an outdated article http://www.glass.lu/Blog/MixingInIoc. Is there any latest documentation to integrating IoC with Glass.Mapper? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 8.2 the old (good) config-based [Sitecore Factory](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Sitecore%20Configuration%20Factory/) IoC container has been extended and [integrated with Microsoft DependencyInjection](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection). Both frameworks are available OOTB now which allows to configure dependencies using either config files or code-based approach.

Before switching back to Castle Windsor (and paying the *integration* price), you may want to evaluate the Microsoft DependencyInjection [capabilities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) and decide if this functionality is sufficient for the project needs. You can also read more about the new Siteore DI in [this article](https://kamsar.net/index.php/2016/08/Dependency-Injection-in-Sitecore-8-2/).

Comment: Hi @Serge, I was looking for glass mapper documentation so that i can use the same IoC for glass mapper classes in addition to using IoC for sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

We could use latest glass mapper without mixing IoC and Request for documentation to mix in IoC has been created here  https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/308